# How to convert .max files to .egg on linux

Tags: 3d, models, python, file-format, 3dsmax

I am very new to 3d graphics and game engines and panda3d and python. I followed few panda3d tutorials and now I want to test them with few new models. High majority of 3d models in the internet are in .max format.

Is there a way to convert these models to a format that can be used with panda3d. (.egg or .bam, I think). I am using linux. Thank you

Comment: .egg files are models? I thought they were something to do with python module installing.

Comment: Panda re-used the term, it is one of their packed model formats. Nothing to do with Python eggs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only program that can reliably open .max files is 3DS Max itself. From Max you can export to something more open and portable like fbx.

There's a free trial version of Max available from http://usa.autodesk.com/3ds-max/trial/?nd=1 which should do the job, although it won't run on Linux...

Comment: The best way I've found to get data out of 3DS Max is to use the OpenCollada exporter. The built in Collada support in 3DS Max is horribly broken, so stay away from that! FBX is fine too, but it's a proprietary format with limited support in the open source world, which can make it more difficult to work with.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Converting_from_3D_Studio_Max shows how to use the exporter.

Answer (score -2):

There's way more to .max files than the simple 3d model. Lots of information that makes the animation work properly. Also, blender does not support animation. The only format blender supports that will recognize the module is .3ds, but you'll lose a lot of important information that is stored in the .max file.
Blender is okay, but just a simple 3d animation program.
If you want a good 3d moduling software for linux, you should try Maya.

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually address the question at all.

Comment: Blender supports animation just as well as the big 3d packages. Also note that .max is a binary proprietary format that only 3D Studio Max understands. .3ds is a completely different, unrelated format.