# How to load .max files to Panda3D

Tags: 3d, models, file-format, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert .max files to .egg on linux](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11231/how-to-convert-max-files-to-egg-on-linux)

Is there a way to load .max files directly to Panda3D engine? I am running Panda3D on linux so converting them using 3ds max is bit difficult.
Or at least is there a work around this problem?

Comment: I wanted to know whether .max files can be loaded to Panda3D directly. By closing this question I think you are suggesting .max files cannot be be loaded to Panda3D directly.

Comment: That seems to be the case, seeing as one of the answers to your other question directly links to the official Panda3D wiki which explains using 3dsmax to do the conversion. You got two very good answers.